# variable is getting appended to some lines of my text file

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a script that is supposed to pick up some data from a JSON API in jenkins and parse the API to get some data.The script does this for 3 jenkins instances.
the jenkins instances are stored in a file instance.txt which has jenkins instance name and api token for authentication
the script is

```
for i in `cat instance.txt`; do
        api=`echo $i | cut -d ":" -f2`
        instance=`echo $i | cut -d ":" -f1`
        echo "start collecting the data"
        echo $instance
        curl -u user:$api -s -k "https://$instance/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1" | jq '.plugins[]|{version,longName}' -c  | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/,/:/g' | cut -d ":" -f2,4 | tr -d "{ }" | sed 's/$/:'$instance'/'>> plugins.txt
        done
```

the instance file is instance.txt

```
instance1:apitoken1
instance2:apitoken2
instance3:apitoken3
```

now the issue is the file gets created and appended with the respective instance but along with that some lines also gets appended with the value "$instance" and i am not sure why that is happening
can someone help me out here

my output file looks something similar to

```
version1:name1:$instance
version2:name2:$instance
.....
versionx:namex:$instance
```

the rest of the lines in the text file look correct but i am not able to figure out why the $instance is getting appended in the file.
i tried printing the $instance variable value and it doesnot print null value anywhere as well, it prints the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing,

```
sed 's/$/:'$instance'/'
```

to

```
sed "s/$/:$instance/"
```